One Time Pad (OTP) algorithm implementation on a server
I am trying to implement the OTP algorithm for encrypting & decrypting messages on a server (c++ server with c# client). What I am struggling with is how to make it so both the server and the client will hold the key of each message.
Should the sending side pass the key with the message somehow? And how to do it without breaking the entire purpose of the encryption? I am open for suggestions.

If you try to pass the key along you will just kick the can down the road in that you have to encrypt that key somehow. You have to have some way to pass the key pad before transmission or you just reduce the security of the OTP to whatever algorithm you used to encrypt the pad.

The point of a one time pad is both sides already have a shared list of keys to xor with that was pre shared using some other secure channel (usually a physical passing of the codebook between two individuals). You can't transmit the keys. If you don't have a way to pre share the content of the code book (and remember you can only transmit as much data as your codebook is in size so you need to pre share as much Mb of keys as you ever plan on sending) you should choose some other form of encryption.
You likey much better off using a standard symmetric stream cipher like AES where you only need to pre share a small key and that key generates the psudorandom bytes your data is encrypted with.

Weird why I got it as a possible challenge
